# Installing visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, installation, iso

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Visual Studion iso file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755353/visual-studion-iso-file)
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774852/have-an-exe-file-that-opens-to

I just down loaded visual studio 2010 and I went through the installation process of choicing a location and I thought I could now use the program. But it is asking me to burn the image to a disk. I don't understand because I thought this was an exe file. But the name of the file is: en_visual_studio_2010_premium_x86_dvd. How do I change it to an exe file so that I can use it. It there a way for me to convert it. I kind of remember the instructions saying something like you have to change the extension to exe. Could I go back make the change in the extension and redownload? I could have gotten a copy of the program at school but I was told I could download the exe file to my computer. I'm confused.

Comment: is the file a .iso file? If so, get a virtual optical drive and mount the image with that. One such program is daemontools (free for personal use).

Comment: Questions about programming tools are on topic here.  Please stop voting to migrate this to SuperUser.

Comment: @fors,I have used same.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't. The file they provide is an ISO, which is a DVD image intended to be burned.

You do have other options: You may want to mount the ISO into a virtual optical drive, using software like [Daemon Tools Lite](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/products/dtLite) or [Alcohol 120%](http://www.alcohol-soft.com/).

Another option is to extract the files from the ISO to a folder, using a compressing software like [WinRAR](http://www.win-rar.com/download.html), [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), etc..

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the disc image for it... I got a copy from school and that's what I downloaded as well. Get a program like Daemon Tool Lite or something to mount the image.

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](http://www.magiciso.com/Setup_MagicISO.exe) to download magic ISO. This program will look similar to this when you open that file that is currently giving you problems:

[image]

Right-Click the cd icon in the upper left tray and right click it. Choose "Extract" and select a destination folder for your files.

When that's done navigate to the folder and run the setup.exe file found there.

Comment: I have use same tool.I am able to install vs 2010 through this software.But problem in sql server 2008.